# How to get the page number where a match is found when searching PDF docs using iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to extract the page number where the search string is found.

Please see below my partial code:

```
For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(TextPDF,nino_pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
     nino_pattern = match.Value
     page = code to get the page number where the search string is found
     ToalPage = Reader.NumberOfPages
     FileWriter.WriteLine(filename & vbTab & nino_pattern & vbTab & Page & ToalPage)
Next
```

Comment: If its VB.net why have you marked it c#?

Comment: If answer is provided in C#, i can convert the code into VBnet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Particular Word in PDF using Itextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485548/search-particular-word-in-pdf-using-itextsharp) it's in C# but will get you exactly what you need.